# Erro: sequência de escape não reconhecida [C#]

Tags: c#, cmd

Para este trecho de código em meu programa recebo o alerta de erro de que ele considera que o comando possui uma sequência de escape invalida, isto é, não reconhecida.

```
string.Format("/c {0}", "cd .\Debug & imagem.png");
```

Como proceder e fazer com que ele seja capaz de reconhecer o código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O link a seguir demonstra como é possível ignorar isso: [ERRO CS1009](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1009)

Basicamente, no caso apresentado bastaria que fosse colocado o caractere arroba`@` em frente ao comando ou então que fosse inserida mais uma barra invertida `\` ao comando. 
Ficando assim:

```
@"cd .\Debug & imagem.png"
```

ou

```
"cd .\\Debug & imagem.png"
```